# classicthesis small margin

Tags: margins, classicthesis

Using classicthessis default margins I would say that page headers (with page number) are too close to page margin... So close that the printer is not going to print them.

Is this the correct way to use classicthesis? Is there any reason for this short margin?

Here is a test document:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
\section{section}

Bla bla bla.
Bla bla bla.
Bla bla bla.
Bla bla bla.
Bla bla bla.

\end{document}
```

and a screenshot of the resulting PDF:

[image]

Comment: You need to set the page parameters with options to `scrbook`.

Comment: Try `\documentclass[headinclude]{scrbook}`. But note that `classicthesis` breaks many features of `KOMA-Script`.

Comment: Is `\setlength{\topmargin}{10mm}` a solution? Or Add +10: `\addtolength{\topmargin}{10mm}`

Comment: @egreg what are the page parameters? I tried to add "a4paper" to the options of scrbook but nothing changes.

Comment: @esdd thanks! headinclude solves the problem! Wonder why it is not active by default.

Comment: @Emanuele I think the creator of KOMA script classes has some weird fetish for small margins. Judging by everything-but-beautiful KOMA Script manual itself.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip No, the small margins are a design decision of the `classicthesis` author. If you use `\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}` after loading `classicthesis`, you can see which margins would be suggested by KOMA-Script. Or simple remove the `classicthesis` package.

Comment: @esdd classicthesis loves big margins :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `classicthesis` changes amongst other things the textarea and the default margins of the class. Without option `minionpro`

```
\areaset[current]{336pt}{750pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}%
\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}%
```

is used to get a small `\textwidth` and a large `\textheight`.

If you really want to use `classicthesis` you can use

```
\documentclass[headinclude]{scrbook}
```

Then the head counts to the text body and the resulting `\textheight` is 713.65pt instead 750pt.

Another possibility is changing the size of the textarea after loading `classicthesis` again. This can be done by another `\areaset` command or something like `\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}`.